# rails 4 how to pass post_id to the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have some problems with my app, i have posts, posts has_many responces
when i create new responce to the post, not added in the db 'responce' post_id
my routes.rb

```
resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :responces
  end
```

controller

```
class ResponcesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @responce = @post.responces.new(post_id:params[:post_id])
    end

    def create
        @responce = current_user.responces.build(responce_params)
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    if @responce.save
      flash[:success] = "Вы откликнулись на задание"
      redirect_to post_path @post
    else
    render 'new'
  end
    end

    def show
    end

    private

    def responce_params
        params.require(:responce).permit(:price, :comment, :post_id)
    end
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for([@post, @responce]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :price %>
<%= f.submit "GO", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

but if add to the view this

```
<%= f.collection_select :post_id, Post.all, :id, :name %>
```

rails create post_id to the db

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing several things the wrong way.

**First**: I don't think you need two separate resources for the same model. I'd recomend nesting all three resources upon each other like this.

```
resource :categories do 
  resource :posts do 
     resource :responces 
  end
end
```

This way you'll be able to find the needed category_id and post_id in the params hash.

I'd also recomend adding `:shalow => true` to the `:categories` resource to make your routes a bit prettier.

**Second**: you need to assign the `params[:post_id]` in your create action, like this.

```
    @responce = current_user.responces.build(responce_params)
    @responce.post_id = params[:post_id]
    @post = @responce.post
```

**Alternatevely** you can just add a hidden field to your form like I show below, but it I don't like that approach, 'cause it can lead to security risks.

```
<%= form_for([@post, @responce]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :price %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
  <%= f.submit "GO", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you aren't passing in the post_id.  You probably want something like this:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @responce]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :price %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
<%= f.submit "GO", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The hidden field will pass the id of the current post into your form as the post_id parameter.